# React: Fetched data, but no access to object properties

Tags: reactjs, typescript, properties, fetch

I successfully fetched data from an API call, in console I see the result, but I can't access object properties or display them.

```
interface Data {
    data: []
    isLoading: boolean
}
function About() {

    const  [ dataUser, setDataUser ] = useState<Data>({data: [], isLoading: false})

    useEffect(() => {
        setDataUser({data: [], isLoading: true})

        fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
        .then(response => {
            if (!response.ok) {
                throw new Error("Failed with HTTP code " + response.status);
            }
            return response;
        })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => setDataUser( {data: data, isLoading: false} ))
        .catch((err) => {console.log(err)})
    }, [])

    const user = dataUser.data.map(item => { 
        console.log(item)        //works
        console.log(item.id)     //doesn't work (error: "Property 'id' does not exist on type 'never'.")
        return (<li>{item.name}</li>)   //another error ("Objects are not valid as a React child...")
    })

    return (
        <div>
            {user}
        </div>
    )
}

export default About
```

EDIT

console.log(dataUser.data) ->
[image]

I added code for checking if response was ok and everything is fine with that.

console.log(item) ->
[image]

Comment: Could you please show us a snippet of `dataUser.data` so we can see the structure?

Comment: It's not the problem, but like most people you're missing a step in your `fetch` (if a footgun in the `fetch` API), you need to check for HTTP success (`response.ok`) before calling `json`. More [on my anemic little blog](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2018/06/common-fetch-errors.html).

Comment: It's *probably* not the problem, but you're trying to create an invalid DOM structure. You can't have `li` as a direct child of `div`.

Comment: *"Objects are not valid as a React child..."* tells you that `item.name` is an object. So yeah, we need to know what the format of the data in the `data` array is.

Comment: Sure, I edited now

Comment: What is logged by `console.log(item)`?  There's something screwy going on here.  When I run a functionally equivalent snippet in a chrome console, it works fine.

Comment: Now I added an image so you can see.. I can't access to _item.name_ for example or any other property

Comment: I can't explain what's wrong.  I literally copied and pasted your code into a react playground, and it worked as expected.  https://jscomplete.com/playground/s441296

Comment: I got an error "_Property 'name' does not exist on type 'never'._" Can't display it, can't do console.log() without an error. I'm using typescript, so I don't know if maybe that's the reason for error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is your interface.  I hadn't realized this was a compile-time error, not a run-time error.

```ts
interface Data {
    data: any[],
    isLoading: boolean,
}
```

The issue is that you're defining `Data.data` to be an empty array, and the elements of an empty array are of type `never`.  That means that `item` in your `map()` callback is of type `never`, and `never` has no properties.

You probably want `Data.data` to be something other than `any[]` so that `item` has strongly-typed values, but this should unblock you.

Comment: Ok, so what should I write instead? I tried with 'null' but still not working, I don't have any other ideas

Comment: You *can* use `any`, but you should use whatever shape the data items are.  In this case, it's the shape of the objects retrieved by `fetch()`: `{ id: number, name: string, username: string, ... }`, but I assume that's not going to be your actual data.

Comment: Yes, it's fine now.. and also this needs to be added: `dataUser.data.map((item: { id: any; name: string; }) => { })` or for any other property

Comment: Strange.  That last part shouldn't be needed.

Comment: @Aniram - You don't need to type the `item` parameter if you define the type of `Data.data` properly. From your comment there, it should be `data: {id: any; name: string; /*...*/}[]` but A) I'd probably define a type for `{id: any; name: string; /*...*/}` and then use `data: ThatType[]`, and B) `id: any` is suspect, it should be possible to be more specific about the type of `id`.